# como verificar con Adafruit_Fingerprint.h si la huella existe y enrrolar con las misma?

Tags: arduino, librería, sensor

Tengo el problema de que requiero verificar una huella antes de ser registrada, mi problema es que tengo que poner 3 veces el dedo en el sensor dactilar, lo cual prefiero hacerlo solo dos veces que es lo normal. Lo de verificar quedo bien, solo que no se porque tengo que quitar mi dedo para continuar con el registro de esta, que lo hago en el método `getFingerprintEnroll()`.

Mi expectativa es colocar por primera vez el dedo en el sensor, aquí verifico que la huella no exista, en caso de que no este registrada, haga la primera captura de esta para su registro sin tener la necesidad de quitar el dedo de dicho sensor y ya el resto no importa.

En mi `loop` tengo algo como:

```
id = readnumber();
// ...
while ((huella = finger.getImage()) != FINGERPRINT_OK);
if (getFingerprintIDez() != -1) {
    Serial.println("exist");
    return;  
} else {
    Serial.println("no_exist");  
    while (!  getFingerprintEnroll() );
}
```

Mis métodos usados son:

```
int getFingerprintIDez() {
    uint8_t p = huella;
    if (p != FINGERPRINT_OK)  return -1;
    p = finger.image2Tz();
    if (p != FINGERPRINT_OK)  return -1;
    p = finger.fingerFastSearch();
    if (p != FINGERPRINT_OK)  return -1;
    return finger.fingerID; 
}

uint8_t getFingerprintEnroll() {
  int p = -1;
  while (p != FINGERPRINT_OK) {
    p = finger.getImage(); // aqui queda pausada hasta que quite mi dedo
  }
  //...
}
```